# Using Dismax as parser, why doesn't Solr always expand synonyms?

Tags: solr

Our application does some parsing of its own before the query is sent to Solr, which means that searching for the word court produces the following query:

`((+court))`

This works fine using the Standard Query Parser. But using the Dismax parser, synonyms no longer get expanded, yielding less search results. Using Solr Admin, I see that if I remove the parentheses the synonyms do get expanded.

Is there a reason that the parentheses cause different behaviour using Dismax? How do I get them to behave consistently?

Comment: How are you determining that the synonyms are not being expanded? If I click the "debugQuery" checkbox and run a query in the Solr Admin it looks like synonyms are expanded for my search "((+GB))" regardless of the parser that I use: `"parsedquery":"+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((Synonym(author_txt_en:gb author_txt_en:gib author_txt_en:gigabyt author_txt_en:gigabyt))^1.0)) ()"`

Comment: @HectorCorrea I determined it by both the number of search results and debugQuery. For some reason switching to edismax makes it work. Could it be a bug in Solr 8.11.2?